Do we need a global vector space basis to define a manifold?
Mathematically, a manifold is defined as a topological space that locally looks flat (with a few other properties), and a topological space is a set with a topology. Now based on this definition, I try to define a manifold as follows:
Consider the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. Take the Cartesian product of this set with itself, and define $U = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. Note that $U$ is just a set of points, it is not equipped with a set of basis or whatsoever. Now I invoke Axiom schema from ZFC to define:
$$M=\left\{ (m_1, m_2) \in U \,\middle|\,m_1^2 + m_2^2 = 1 \right\}.$$
This is just a set of points. I can give topology to this set, and consider it as a manifold. Is this correct? I did not use any basis to define $M$, even though, I definitely could.
What confuses me is that every introductory book that I have seen so far, says that consider this geometrical object with this definite shape ___, it can be considered as a manifold. For example, often, a circle is given as an example of a manifold. But to me, it seems that $M$ that I just defined above has no geometrical meaning, without a given basis.
Furthermore in comment section people talk about diffeomorphism, which is a map that maps a manifold to another manifold. But this is irrelevant to my question. Only one of these statement is correct:

To define a manifold, one needs pick a vector space basis and establish a coordinate system first, and then define the manifold with the help of that coordinate system. For example, one can pick Cartesian coordinate system and say that $x^2+y^2=1$ is a manifold.

A manifold can be defined without any vector space basis just fine, but if someone is interested, they can pick some basis to represent their whole manifold inside their coordinate system.


Edit: I apologize for asking such an elementary question.
Edit2: For future readers, the basis here meant to be a global vector space where the whole manifold would reside in. Not the collection of open sets which defines the topology. My original question stemmed from the fact that geometrical objects are usually shown in a vector space, therefore I thought that when it is said a "circle" is a manifold it means the manifold itself has to live inside a global vector space. After all, by changing the basis one can change the shape of an object. Therefore, talking about a circle without having a pre-existing basis is meaningless. Because what looks like a circle in one basis, may look like an elliptical in other basis. @XanderHenderson told me that it is possible to define such objects purely topologically and that actually solved the problem.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comments have been moved to chat.  Please note that further comments here will be deleted---please respond in chat.

A proper answer to this question would require, as a prerequisite, a course in topology and a followup half-course in differential topology. I'm going to assume all those prerequisites, and pick out just the very basic definitions needed to sort out all of these things. These will be standard definitions. I'm not claiming that you will find these definitions all stated in exactly this way in any particular wiki or web site or textbook. Instead I am giving definitions that every topologist can accept, laid out in such a way as to address most directly the issues you have brought up in your post.

Coordinate charts
Manifolds
Smooth submanifold charts in Euclidean
space
Smooth submanifolds of Euclidean space

After giving these definitions, I'll then discuss some of the things you bring up in your post.
Definition 1: Coordinate charts. Given a topological space $M$, a coordinate chart of $M$ in $\mathbb R^n$ consists of a function $\phi : U \to V$ such that $U \subset M$ is open, $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ is open, and $\phi$ is a homeomorphism (with respect to subspace topologies on $U$ and $V$).
Note: There is no requirement in the definition of a coordinate chart that the domain of $\phi$ must be all of $M$: it might be all of $M$; but then again it might not be.
Definition 2: Manifolds. Given a topological space $M$, to say that $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold means that $M$ is metrizable (sometimes different properties are used in place of metrizability), and there exists a set of coordinate charts $\{\phi_i : U_i \to V_i\}_i$ of $M$ in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $M = \bigcup_i U_i$.
The very simplest example of an $n$-manifold that is usually taught is $\mathbb R^n$ itself.
The next simplest example of an $n$-manifold that is usually taught, for the case $n=1$, is the circle $S^1 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ with the subspace topology induced from $\mathbb R^2$. In the chat you question the statement that this is the "simplest example", and indeed it is not as simple as $\mathbb R^1$ itself. After that, though, it is the next simplest example of a manifold in the following pedagogical sense: it is definitely the very first example of a $1$- manifold that I introduce in my topology class after $\mathbb R^1$, and then I would assign as an (easy) exercise:

Prove that $S^1$ is a $1$-manifold (according to Definition 2).

Note: as is required in Definition 2, a topology on $S^1$ has been given by specifying it to be the subspace topology induced from $\mathbb R^2$.
Note: Regarding definition 2, the topological space $M$ must be  given. That is to say, its underlying point set is given, and its topology is given. As you learn in a first topology course, there are many ways for a topology to be given.
Definition 3: Smooth submanifold charts in Euclidean space. Consider integers $0 \le k \le n$, and consider $\mathbb R^k$ embedded in $\mathbb R^n$ as the subspace
$$\mathbb R^k = \{(x_1,...,x_k,\underbrace{0,...,0}_{\text{$n-k$ times}})\} \subset \mathbb R^n
$$
Given a subspace $M \subset \mathbb R^n$, a smooth $k$-dimensional submanifold chart for $M$ is a function $g : W \to \mathbb Y$ such that $W \subset \mathbb R^n$ is open, $Y \subset \mathbb R^n$ is open, $\phi : W \to Y$ is a smooth bijection with smooth inverse, and
$$\phi(W \cap M) = Y \cap \mathbb R^k
$$
Definition 4: Smooth $k$-dimensional submanifolds of Euclidean space. Given a subspace $M \subset \mathbb R^n$, to say that $M$ is a smooth $k$-dimensional submanifold of Euclidean space means that there exists a set $\{g_i : W_i \to Y_i\}_i$ of smooth $k$-dimensional submanifold charts in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $M = \bigcup_i (W_i \cap M)$.
In my class I would assign two exercises:

Prove that $S^1$ is a smooth $1$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ (Definition 4).


Prove that if $M$ is a smooth $k$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ (Definition 4) then $M$ is a $k$-dimensional manifold (Definition 2).


Finally, regarding points 1 and 2 in your post, notice that "picking a basis" is irrelevant to these definitions. Nonetheless a topological space must be given: perhaps an abstract one (as in Definition 2); or perhaps a subspace of some Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$ (as in Definition 4).

One last comment. These four definitions are not yet the end of the story of manifolds, because there is still an abstract concept of a smooth manifold. The standard definition would start with a given manifold $M$ (Definition 2), which itself requires that $M$ be given to start with as a topological space. The definition then proceeds by requiring the existence of a collection of charts satisfying the standard requirement $\bigcup_i U_i=M$, but also satisfying a new requirement of "smooth overlap maps". But that is beyond the scope of your question.

In a comment that our mod helpfully deleted, the OP explained that by the word "basis" they do not mean a basis of topology but a basis of a vector space containing the manifold in question.

Ah, that explains one or two issues with the post. So I deleted one short paragraph.
